# Android listView overlapping elements

Tags: android, listview, overlap

Context:
I've managed to create a custom BaseAdapter for my ListView which renders my elements correctly. I've got a nice 4x4 grid of items beautifully drawn.

Now I'd like to change the state of one of the items on pressed (like a button OnPressed state). I've achieved this with a custom control derived from button, and some custom states. This allows me to programatically or on touch, change the state of the item in question. Perfect.

Problem:
Now I'd like the elements (in a given state) to exceed the bounds provided by the listView.
 The adapter's getView method returns a view, but this (AFAIK) fits within the columns provided, with the listview expanding to fit the view returned. What I want is to specify the height of each row, but allow the item to fill beyond these bounds. For example, on press I'd like to draw a big circle around the item touched - this circle would overlap other elements as it encompasses the item; the circle exceeds the bounds of the element it encircles.

Is there a simple padding or layout parameter to specify allowing the Drawable to exceed the bounds of the space allocated by the list view? Or do I need another view of a circle ontop of the ListView and position at the right place on touch? (the circle is currently a background drawable of the button, shown via a selector for the correct state).